# Copy permalink to clipboard automatically when publish/update posts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, save-post

When a post gets published/updated, a message will be displayed which gives the permalink. Yes we can copy the permalink to clipboard manually, but I want it to be copied automatically, just like it shows the message.

My plan is,  enqueue my custom javascript file on save_post action.

**1. First, test if the script will run successfully.**

```php
function ff_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', false);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ff_load_scripts');
```

The `custom.js` is just an alert():

```js
alert("Yes it run.");
```

Yes, it can alert successfully.

**2. Second, hook it to the '`save_post`' action.**

```php
function ff_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', false);
}
function ff_copy_permalink() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ff_load_scripts');
}
add_action('save_past', 'ff_copy_permalink');
```

However, it doesn't run.

Please advise, thanks in advance!

Comment: `save_post` happens in the server, often in the background. You can’t run JS when it occurs.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. Which hook shall I use, please? When post updated, `Post updated.  View Post` shows up, it's ll be a nice place to add the JS I think, but I haven't found the way yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it! **Use the `post_updated_messages` hook instead**.

```php
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', function( $messages )
{
    // Get the permalink
    $link = esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) );

    // Copy the permalink automatically
    $autocopy = '<script type="text/javascript">navigator.clipboard.writeText("%s");</script>';

    // `6` is for publishing
    $messages['post'][6] = sprintf( __('Post published. <a href="%s">View post</a>'. $autocopy), $link, $link);

    // `1` is for updating
    $messages['post'][1] = sprintf( __('Post updated. <a href="%s">View post</a>'. $autocopy), $link, $link);

    return $messages;
} );
```